# Sending JMS messages in WSO2 without specifying all JMS parameters in proxy definition

Tags: oracle, jms, wso2

I got a WSO2 example to work with Oracle based on http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2011/11/configuring-wso2-esb-with-oracle-as-messaging-media/.

My question is: rather than having to specify all the JMS connection parameters in the proxy, is it possible to define the transport sender in axis2.xml and refer to it in the proxy, similar to how you do it with the receiver? I tried defining the sender and reducing the address to the destination name as below. It kinda works but every now and then I get an error:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the /services/WsdlToJmsSender URL
```

My new address:

```
<address uri="jms:/cn=tro_Q_JMS2,cn=OracleDBQueues,cn=ORCL,cn=OracleContext,ou=Services, o=sgi,c=us/>
```

My axis2.xml:

```
 <transportSender name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender">
        <parameter name="default" locked="false">
            <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">ldap://localhost:10389/</parameter>
            <parameter name="server_dn" locked="false">cn=ORCL,cn=OracleContext,ou=Services, o=sgi,c=us</parameter>
            <parameter name="java.naming.security.principal" locked="false">uid=tromanow,ou=Services,o=sgi,c=us</parameter>
            <parameter name="java.naming.security.credentials" locked="false">tromanow</parameter>
            <parameter name="java.naming.security.authentication" locked="false">simple</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.UserName" locked="false">tromanow</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.Password" locked="false">tromanow</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">cn=tro_jms,cn=oracledbconnections,cn=ORCL, cn=OracleContext,ou=Services, o=sgi,c=us</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
        </parameter>
  </transportSender>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to define it in your *axis2.xml* file, you can create an individual Endpoint component (*Main -> Manage -> Service Bus -> Endpoints*), and then just refer that endpoint in your proxy service (or multiple proxies). I am not sure what advantage you would get by defining it in your axis2 file over individual endpoint.

So after you define it, you can refer it in your proxy by:

```
<endpoint key="your_EP"/>
```

where `key` attribute is the name you set for your endpoint.

Comment: I get "Invalid URI provided" when saving the endpoint ( see My New address section in my OP). Looks like he doesn't like the commas in the URI which are required for the LDAP path.

Comment: On another note - even though the solution would make the proxy definition cleaner, I'd  still have to include all the JMS connection parameters for each and every single endpoint. I was hoping for a solution where I specify all the JMS connection stuff at one central spot, be it axis2.xml or somewhere else, and only specify the sender name (or whatever you want to call it) and the queue name when defining my endpoints or proxies.

Comment: @Ya.: In the address URI you provided you are not closing the double quotes. Defining endpoints give you more flexibility to actually have different parameters for different servers/configurations.

Comment: That was a &p error. The actuall URI I'm specifying is: jms:/cn=tro_Q_JMS2, cn=OracleDBQueues, cn=ORCL, cn=OracleContext, ou=Service, so=sgi, c=us?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=cn=tro_jms cn=oracledbconnections cn=ORCL cn=OracleContext ou=Services o=sgi c=us&java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory&java.naming.provider.url=ldap://localhost:10389/&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue&server_dn=cn=ORCL cn=OracleContext ou=Services o=sgi c=us& java.naming.security.principal=uid=tromanow ou=Services o=sgi c=us& java.naming.security.credentials=tromanow& java (...cont.)

Comment: I found a workaround for the URI validation issue. 1- Fill out the address with a dummy but valid URI   2- Switch to code view and edit the address there 3- Save and close. This will by-pass the validations and trick it into accepting the commas. Unfortunately, must repeat whenever making modifications. Seems like a bug to me.